# Trying to better understand OOM memory in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, gpu

I am running a very large convolutional neural network using Keras. When I train the network using the fit command, I generally don't have any issues. When I run using the train_on_batch command, I generally run into out of memory issues. The weird thing however, is that it doesn't instantly run out of memory when trying to pass the data into the network, which I would expect on an OOM error. Instead, I am running out of memory on the 4th or 5th training epoch, when I would expect all of the memory to be allocated already.

One thing I am doing, that may be the cause, is because I have a massive network and large training data sets to accompany said massive network, I try and only run a small amount of data through at a time, resetting the new inputs to the training output each time. Could this be the possible cause of running out of memory after a brief while?

Code added:

```
def read_case(name,file_,parameter):
    """
    Reads the specific parameter data from the given file for the specific case.
    """
    case = file_[name]
    keylist = list(case.keys())
    #print("Keylist {}".format(keylist))
    if keylist:
        shape = list(case[keylist[0]][parameter].shape)
        shape.insert(0,len(keylist))
        mymatrix = numpy.zeros(shape)
        for i,key in enumerate(keylist):
            mymatrix[i] = case[key][parameter][:]

        return mymatrix
```

Then the main loop where I run the neural network

```
    ash_ketchum = NN_Trainer()
    ash_ketchum.training_list = training_list
    ash_ketchum.validation_list = validation_list
    ash_ketchum.library_list.append(lib_one)
    #ash_ketchum.library_list.append(lib_two)

    keylist = list(lib_one.keys())
    testkey = keylist[0]
    input1 =  read_case(testkey,lib_one,'pin_power')
    output1 = read_case(testkey,lib_one,'pin_steamrate')

    model = assemble(input1,output1)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse',metrics=['mae'])

    for i in range(50):
        print(i)
        ash_ketchum.train(model)
        ash_ketchum.validate(model,ash_ketchum.training_list)
```

Comment: How large is your network ? i also use keras a lot with colab, and also only get this error when i use train_on_batch. But always when i restart my session and re-run it clean with cleared GPU_RAM and RAM, it works fine. Did you spectate the same behavior ?

Comment: I am not quite sure but I think when working with batches memory allocation process causes framentation in memory. Which makes new allocations impossible even though there is enough space for a new batch.

Comment: @PaulHigazi My neural network is about 100,000 inputs and 20,000 outputs, 8 layers deep. As far as restarting my sessions, that hasn't really helped me. It's pretty consistent whether its running immediately afterwards or after starting a new session. If I understood your question correctly

Comment: @Meto That would make sense. It would describe the behavior I am seeing. I would try just running using model.fit(), but then I can't train all my data at once, which I was hoping to do using train_on_batch. I've also noticed that using fit with an already trained model leads to some odd behaviors.

Comment: @Brian Andersen (Offtopic) Do you use a FCN (Fully-connected-network) ? I think you know that switching to CNN could solve that overhead quite easy.

Comment: @PaulHigazi This is already a CNN. Specifically I am running a U-NET. I may be able to reduce some of the layers. I haven't really adapted the model I got originally much to be fully honest. But I honestly just have a massive problem I am trying to model.

Comment: -> Better try Multires-Unet, works better on my liver-tissue-samples in comparison to wider, or deeper UNETs without ResNet-blocks. ^^ 

https://github.com/nibtehaz/MultiResUNet/blob/master/MultiResUNet3D.py
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.04049

Comment: Do you use Colab or ur own resources ?

Comment: @PaulHigazi Thanks. I will give it a look. And I use my own resources.

Comment: @BrianAndersen can you share some code? I've had luck with storing my training data in tfrecords format and using `tf.data.Dataset` generator with Keras. That way, you don't hold your data in memory.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 which code would you like to look at specifically? I added some code to the original post